# Does Coldfusion support dynamic arguments?

Tags: python, coldfusion, coldfusion-9

In python there is the `*args` convention I am wondering if CF9 supports something similar.

Here is the python example

```
>>> def func(*args):
        for a in args:
               print a, "is a quality argument"


>>> func(1, 2, 3)
1 is a quality argument
2 is a quality argument
3 is a quality argument
>>>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, CFML has supported dynamic arguments for as long as it has supported user-defined functions.

All arguments, whether explicitly defined, or whether passed in without being defined, exist in the Arguments scope.

The Arguments scope can be treated as both an array and a structure (key/value).

Here is the closest equivalent to your example, using script syntax:

```
function func()
{
        for (a in arguments)
               WriteOutput(arguments[a] & "is a quality argument");
}
```

Note that `a` in this example is the key name, not the value, hence why `arguments[a]` is used.

To be treated as code, the above script must either be within `<cfscript>`..`</cfscript>` tags, or alternatively inside a `component {`..`}` block inside a `.cfc` file.

Here's a couple of tag versions, the first equivalent to the for/in loop:

```
<cffunction name="func">
    <cfloop item="a" collection=#Arguments#>
        <cfoutput>#Arguments[a]# is a quality argument</cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</cffunction>
```

And this one allows you to access the value directly (i.e. `a` is the value here):

```
<cffunction name="func">
    <cfloop index="a" array=#Arguments#>
        <cfoutput>#a# is a quality argument</cfoutput>
    </cfloop>
</cffunction>
```

In Railo* CFML, this last example can be expressed in script as:

```
function func()
{
    loop index="a" array=Arguments
    {
        WriteOutput(a & 'is a quality argument');
    }
}
```

*<sub>*[Railo](http://getrailo.org) is one of two Open Source alternatives to Adobe ColdFusion, the other being [Open BlueDragon](http://openbd.org).</sub>*

Comment: I am having trouble getting your last example to work... the error I am getting is `function keyword is missing in FUNCTION declaration.`... Any suggestions?

Comment: That first example would need to be within <cfscript> block

Comment: `loop index="a" array=Arguments`?  I've never seen this, is this for Railo or something?

Comment: @Henry, yes it appears to be Railo. At least that is what I am guessing after reading [this](https://github.com/cybersonic/MuraSiteGeneratorPlugin/issues/2) discussion.

Comment: Ah, sorry - I thought that worked in ACF too. (Both engines use this syntax for component and function attributes.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, arguments are passed into functions as an array called "arguments".  In addition you can pass in an array called "argumentCollection" into a function.

```
public void function myFunct(){
    var myVar = "";

    if(arrayLen(arguments)){
        myVar = arguments[1];
    }
}
```

Invoking functions with dynamic arguments:

```
myFunc("hello","world");
  OR
myFunc(argumentCollection=["Hello","World"]);
```

Additionally you can extend arguments this way to have named arguments and arguments that are outside the named arguments:

```
public void function myFunction(String arg1){
  var secondArgument = "";

  if(arraylen(arguments) > 1){
    secondArgument = arguments[2];
  }
}

myFunction("Hello","World");
```

Comment: I thought CF started at index 1? Is it different in this case? **Edit** don't forget the first one as well =).

Comment: You can also pass the argumentCollection in as a struct of named arguments. `myFunc(argumentCollection={foo="hello", bar="word"}`

Comment: Also shouldn't len() be ArrayLen()? In the first example.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how the function is called the arguments may be contained in a struct with numeric keys relating to their position (1 based index) or in a struct with the argument name as the key.

if you call a function like this;

```
func(1, "foo");
```

then the arguments will be accessible as arguments[1] and arguments[2]

if the function is called passing in named arguments or using argumentCollection, for example;

```
func(foo=1, bar="foo");
```

then the arguments are accessible as arguments["foo"] and arguments["bar"]